# Screen size detection not working based on Vue 3 computed()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to detect screen size in Nuxt 3?

I'm using the below code, but the size always stays 1200. Computed property is runing before `onMounted()` hook. How to fix this?

```
<template><main ref="page" class="w-100 h-100"> ... </main></template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {computed} from '@vue/reactivity';
import {onMounted, ref} from 'vue';

let size = ref<number>(1200);
const page = ref(null);
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('the se');
  if (page.value) {
    console.log('order');
    size.value = page.value.clientWidth;
  }
});

const isMobile = computed(() => {
  console.log(size.value, 'asfsaf');
  return size.value < 768;
}).value;
const showModal = ref(false);
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't immediately use ref values like `computed(..).value`, this disables the reactivity

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, `onMounted` will be fired in the timeline after the `computed`. So, it's normal for a `computed` to get the initial value because the update happens after that calculation. However, you can use `watchEffect` instead of `computed` and get the last value of `size.value` in your calculation.

```js
import {onMounted, ref, watchEffect} from 'vue';
…
watchEffect(() => {
  isMobile.value = size.value < 768;
});
```

Comment: watchEffect doesn't make sense in this context, you can't return anything from a watcher,  watch/watchEffect returns unwatch function, not a result

Answer (score 0):

[Vueuse](https://vueuse.org/) does provide a lot of handy functions. I suggest you to take a look at [useWindowSize](https://vueuse.org/core/useWindowSize/)

```
import { useWindowSize } from '@vueuse/core'

const { width, height } = useWindowSize()
```